# encryption of database fields across entire row, including bools

Tags: mysql, postgresql, encryption

I've a database table for a website in which **all** of the fields are sensitive data. Each row will belong to different users (of the service, not database users). Usually, I'd implement this by generating an encryption key for each row, encrypting the data in the client app, and then storing the data in binary fields. Each row would also have the encryption key stored in it, and this key would be encrypted by the application's own encryption key.

The unencrypted table schema includes some boolean fields and integers. I'm wondering if encrypting such small values will lead to possible cracking opportunities? I'd also be interested to here if anyone has a better idea on how to do this.

---

The plan is currently to use MySQL, but Postgres is a possibility. The app is a web site, with connections encrypted to and from the app to the browser, and https from the app to the client.

---

Just a quick note about choosing the answer, since several of the answers may be correct I chose @Jack's because not only will it work, but I found it an interesting suggestion in a direction I'd not considered. I really appreciate all the input, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly possible and secure to encrypt a boolean as long as you are using a large enough [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Of course storage requirements go up dramatically, but that is just the price of entry here for the security you are asking for, rather than a 'problem'

Comment: I hadn't considered using a salt (several heads really are better than one:), but that's a good idea. Storage space is cheap in this instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are third party encryption solutions for MySQL that might do the trick.  Check out [Gazzang](http://www.gazzang.com/products/ezncrypt-for-databases.html), [Vormetric](http://www.vormetric.com/), or [Packet General](https://www.packetgeneral.com/).  They all claim to have transparent data encryption for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about those. I've had a quick look and they do a more over arching security (like tables or the entire database) but they're still really interesting and I'll look into them further. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

I want to chime in and say that booleans can absolutely be encrypted. Statistically, (in their encrypted state) half the time they will be true and half the time they will be false. While some of the time it will match the current value and some of the time it will not, one has no way of knowing.

This assumes initialization of the cipher is good and is different for each row, but that is a requirement for any text field as well to prevent them from being open to easy cryptanalysis.

Comment: Each row would have it's own key, and each key would use a different, pseudo randomly generated initialisation vector(IV), so I suppose (hope!) that is covered. Thinking about it, if I'm using a block cipher then I suppose it shouldn't be a problem as, by it's nature, is chopping data into small blocks anyway. Thanks for the input, it's helped with clarifying things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to actually **encrypt** things like boolean, because boolean only have two possible values: true, false, people can guess the value in limited time. it might be better to encrypt the entire record.

Comment: Pick a value -- be it true or false. Flip a coin. XOR the coin flip and your chosen value. Whatever your distribution of chosen values, your outcome should statistically be 50/50.

Comment: I will write plenty of tests for this I think! If I'm not satisfied then I will consider implementing encryption of the entire record, perhaps concatenated into less or one fields, or in a file. The security is more of a concern than performance, as the number of views won't be high enough to make performance a major concern anyway.